# How do I add security group to Azure app service?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-appservice

I have N users accessing an app service in Azure thru a web UI. The app service is protected by AAD and since all N users are internal to organisation, they are added by default to the directory and can access the service thru web UI(by successfully logging in).

I built another application that will access the service but here I want only M users out of the total to be able to use it. Note that all N should be able to access thru web UI but only these M members can use my new application. I have created a database for onboarding users and providing them a unique client id to use with my application but I dont want to use this extra database.

I am exploring AAD groups. I have created a group in my Azure directory and I have added those M users, however I cant figure out to impose the above mentioned constraint in Azure to my app service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is we have to switch on User Assignment for the AAD application in "Managed application in local directory" and then we can add groups there. It solves my problem because now I use the client id and secret of this new AAD app in my project and only those users can use it who are part of the group.